# Something management VS Manage something

Tags: website-design

I have a page listing somethings (licenses e.g.). User can see the list or do some actions related to each one. Now I doubted about the title. Which one is better suited and why ?

- Licenses management
- Manage licenses
- or something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Whent it's clear from the context**

If it's clear from the context, the shortest title, e.g. "Licenses" would be the best since its conveys the same sense ocupying less space.

To find an example, just look at your screen. You probably see "Window" and "Bookmarks" and not "Window Manager" alongside with "Bookmarks Manager".

**When it's not clear from the context**

If it's not clear from the context, or there are other titles that have the word "Licence", it's best to use "Licence Manager" instead of "Manage Licences" since the user can find it easier reading just the first part.

Please, see the follwoing example that shows the situation when it makes sense to include the word manager to clarify the intentions.

[image]